# Use axios interceptor to refresh the token for Next-Auth?

Tags: javascript, next.js, axios, next-auth

I setup Next-Auth and Axios for my NextJs project. I used method getSession() from Next-Auth for axios header. Like this

```
export const ApiAuth = () => {
  const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: API_URL,
  });

  instance.interceptors.request.use(async (request) => {
    const session = await getSession();
    console.log(session);

    if (session) {
      request.headers["Authorization"] = `Bearer ${session.tokens.accessToken}`;
    }
    return request;
  });

  instance.interceptors.response.use(
    (response) => {
      return response;
    },
    (error) => {
      console.log(`error`, error);
      if (error.response.status === 401) {
        console.log("Let refresh Here");
        console.log("And update Next-Auth session data");
      }
    }
  );

  return instance;
};
```

But I don't know how can I update Next-Auth session data from axios interceptor. Could you please show me the way.

I imagine that I will create an api like /api/auth/refresh and this api handle update new access token and refresh token for Next-Auth and return new access token for axios.